# PowerShell wrong encoding when writing to file

Tags: powershell, encoding

I am making a simple PowerShell script to launch using the Task Scheduler. The script should create a file, launch a .exe-Program and redirect all the output to the newly created file.

This is what my script looks like now:

```bsh
# script.ps1
$LogFile = "C:\a\very\long\path\to\logfile.log"
C:
cd 'C:\path\to\exe\directory\' > $LogFile
.\program.exe > $LogFile
```

The program outputs symbols of the German alphabet: Ää Öö Üü ß. When I launch the program without file writing, it output the symbol the way it should: `ä`, `ü`. However, when I redirect the output to the log file, `ä` turns into `õ` and `ü` turns into `³`.

I tried appending `chcp 65001` and `$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ '*:Encoding' = 'utf8' }`, but it didn't have any effect.

Funnily enough, this problem happens only in PowerShell. A similar script in Batch doesn't have this problem. Is there a way to fix it in PowerShell?

P. S. My PowerShell version is 5.1

Comment: Open your ps1 file using notepad++ and change the encoding type and save it... Should work..

Comment: The cmdlet [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7) has a parameter `-Encoding`. Read the help to learn how to use it please.

Answer (score 2):

From PowerShell, external program (.exe) output encoding is managed by `[Console]::OutputEncoding`. If you want UTF8, then that property needs to have a UTF8 encoding.

```
$BackupEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
.\program.exe > $LogFile
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $BackupEncoding
```

**Note:** The above solution is UTF8 with BOM. In PowerShell Core 6.2+ and PowerShell 7, UTF8 with no BOM is the default encoding in these cases.